# How to access Tableau Metadata API (w/SSO Azure Authentication) from Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, azure, graphql, tableau-api, oracle12c

I am using the GraphiQL interface to query the Tableau Metadata API.

I need to get the data into Oracle.

How can this be done? I have explored both

- https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/docs/meta_api_auth.html#signin
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl#authentication

With no luck...Can this be done natively from Oracle or additional tools/software needed?

Comment: I ended up using Python to access the API.